GTAG Collect Data Does Not Return an Event
I have a site made with Wordpress. I added GTAG code and I want to receive an event when the button is pressed with the dataLayer push feature. However, when the button is clicked, collect data does not return an event. When I add the same code to the HTML file, I see that collect data is coming. So there seems to be no problem with the code block I wrote. I use litespeed and wordfence on the site. Litespeed does not cache the page with the buttons. I also defined all requests related to Google in wordfence. Can anyone give me any ideas?
This is my dataLayer script code
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
dataLayer.push({
    event: "phone_appointment"
});

